# Airpods microphone is noisy on Macbook (input format: 8 Hz, 1 ch 16 bit, SCO codec)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone, airpods

Airpods microphone has very poor quality on my Macbook (input format: 8 Hz, 1 ch 16 bit processed by SCO codec):

[image: Audio midi setup]

[image: codec info]

As a temporary solution, I use the built-in microphone but I'd like to find out how to fix it on Airpods side.

**Device info:**

- MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
- macOS Mojave 10.14.4
- AirPods 1